# Why is record considered product type but class not so in java?

Tags: java, oop, record, algebraic-data-types, type-theory

Java 16 is going to officially deliver the [record feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), which [according to one of the authors](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/amber/datum.html) is a form of product types.

I understand record's internal states range from a Cartesian product space constructed from the member fields, thus is an example of product type. But isn't it the same with traditional OOP classes? Why rarely do programmers consider classes to be an example of product type?

(In fact, I tend to feel that with inheritance, superclass is also a weak kind of sum type for its subclasses.)

Comment: I've been programming for about 30 years and just learned the term "product type". Most programmers outside the functional-language niche don't think in type theory in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

From a type theory perspective, a cartesian product type is a set of tuples consisting of the values of the individual "field" types.  It does not allow for mutation.  A Java 14+ `record` type is immutable, so there is a good match between `record` and cartesian product types.

From the same perspective, an object type has to allow for mutation. However, classical type theory does not allow (mathematical) values to mutate.  That means that an object type has to be modeled as a set of functions (lambda expressions) that map from one state of an object to the next state.

(The same approach is used to model mutation in a pure functional language.  Mutation is modeled by creating a new state / environment / context from a previous one.)

So ....

> But isn't it the same with traditional OOP classes?

No; see above.

> Why rarely do programmers consider classes to be an example of product type?

Well, basically because they would be wrong to do that.

Type theory is not a matter of opinion.  It is mathematics.  A mathematical proposition is either provably correct or not.  A proposed type theory for as programming language is either provably correct (within certain constraints) or not.  Any proposed type theory for OO that does not support mutation is clearly incorrect, because mutation of an object's state is central to OO.

There are good textbooks on type theory.  If you really want to understand this stuff, you should buy one and read it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know immutability is this important for a qualified ADT.

Comment: What is a "qualified ADT"?  I've never heard of the term.

Comment: It seems I was misusing the terms, but I meant "a cartesian product type ... does not allow for mutation" from your answer. I was trying to rephrase (to make sure I understand it correctly), that if a type (say an object type) allows for mutation, it is not qualified as a cartesian product type even if it is "consisting of the values of the individual "field" types."

Comment: Well, different people use "cartesian product" to mean different things.  But from a type theory / mathematical perspective a cartesian product is composed of pure mathematical values, and mathematical values are immutable.  So I think what you said is correct.  From this perspective.  But like I said, some people *may* use "cartesian product" differently.

Comment: Besides, I think you are "over-reading" the JEP text.  It says *"A product type gets its name from cartesian product, because its value set is the cartesian product of the value sets of a vector of types."*.  This does not say that a product type is a cartesian product.  It says that it **gets its name from** a cartesian product.   As I said before, if you really want to understand this stuff, find a good textbook on mathematical type theory.  Don't try and understand it by reverse engineering the informal text of a JEP.